# sed to replace random site urls in ifrrame

Tags: regex, iframe, sed, sh

my problem there is alot of pages infacted with iframe each one of them have different url or  different  id
here  is example

```
<iframe src="http://xxxxxx.xxxx/xxxx.xxx" width=xxx height=xxx style="visibility: hidden"><iframe>
```

or

```
<iframe src="http://xxxxxx.xxxx/xxxx.xxx?xxx=xxxx" width=xxx height=xxx style="visibility: hidden"><iframe>
```

where all xxx are random some times
what i need to do is to remove,replace  this iframe  with blank
like this

```
sed -i 's%<iframe src="xxx://xxxxxx.xxxx/xxxx.xxx?xxx=xxxx" width=xxx height=xxx style="visibility: hidden"><iframe>%%g' file
```

sorry about my bad english 
thanks in advance

Comment: Okay, now what is the question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question is not very clear but from what I understand you want to remove all iframes with the style="visibility:hidden" from the file.

Something like this should work for you:

```
sed -i 's%<iframe[^>]+style="visibility: hidden"></iframe>%%g' file
```

...or a bit more specific:

```
sed -i 's%<iframe src="[^"]+" width=[a-z0-9%]+ height=[a-z0-9%]+ style="visibility: hidden"></iframe>%%g file
```

Comment: thanks for you hard work the question is 
where all xxx are random some times (what i need to do is to remove,replace this iframe with blank)